# partial admin on windows 10 to access for updating existing apps?

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

for understandable reasons work accounts are not admin.

however if that worker is a developer, they need access to run software updates on tools such as Visual Studio Code.

is there a way to provision access to users that they can not install new software but could update existing software ? maybe using other tools such as chocolatey?

Answer (score 2):

Normally Visual Studio Code is installed in a *per-user* location which, by definition, the has user control over. E.g.:

```
C:\Users\SonicSoul\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
```

But if it has been installed in a *"protected location"*, *e.g.*:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
```

You would grant the users **Modify** control to the Visual Studio Code folder:

[image]

**Note**: You don't grant them all the way up to **Full Control**, only **Modify**. Full Control also includes the ability to modify the Access Control List (ACL) on the folder/files. You would only want to grant **Modify**, which lets them create/modify/delete files in the `VS Code Folder`.

Comment: +1 although there's a caveat here... if the program also installs services, you really do need administrative privileges on order to update the services as well.

Comment: @LPChip Checking two machines, i don't see any services related to **Visual Studio Code**. And i just installed it on a virtual machine to check i wasn't crazy. What's it called?

Comment: I'm not saying there are services, just that if there are this is not going to work. Someone may decide that this applies to them (but they have it with another program), then figure out its not working and don't know why. Do note, the developer is given as an example, and so is Visual Studio Code. I did give you the +1 which is my way of saying, this is correct. :)